# Install Angular with NPM I

Tags: angular, npm

If I do not have Angular installed on my machine, but pull down a repository that uses Angular and run `npm i`, should Angular be automatically installed?

I ran npm i, and then ng serve --open and ng was not recognized as a command until I separately installed the Angular CLI

Comment: I think if you have angular/cli installed globally it should work.

Answer (score 1):

if you run npm i without specifient any package you wont install anything

if you want to execute Ng serve you will need to install Angular core with the following command

**npm i @angular/core**

and then execute

**npm install -g @angular/cli**

in order to run ng serve -o

I Hope this work for you